# Rigging Short Arms on a Fat Character

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to rig my character here: [Character Photo](https://www.instagram.com/p/BwCnkYGHWTa/)

[image]
[image]
He has short little arms/legs and a fat body. As you can imagine - there is a lot of awkward deforming with automatic weights. I've been doing custom weight painting - but still struggling to get great results.

Do you have any tips, methods, or examples of similar rigs? I've been watching rigging tutorials on CG Cookie and Youtube, but this character is a bit uncommon in terms of his proportions.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please show us a picture of the character wire and the rig, in ortographic views; I think the main problem is to find the appropriate position of the bones.

Comment: I updated the post with more images